# android retrofit patch request

Tags: android, request, retrofit

Почему не работает калбек в функции patchUser?
Мы отсылаем данные и в ответ получаем эти же данные. Я хочу проверить правильно ли вообще сформирован запрос. Проверку я организовываю тем, что в случае успешной передачи у нас меняется одна из строк на экране. Но пройдя точкой останова программа не идет дальше строчки   `api.patchUser(id,token, user01,new Callback<user>(){`

Код я привожу ниже

```
package com.sancho.clienttest;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.DELETE;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Header;
import retrofit.http.PATCH;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.http.Path;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class SuccessLog extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView text;
    TextView uInfo;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    SharedPreferences sToken;
    user   users;
    String jwtToken;
    String id, email, group,sex,firstname,lastname;
    String name;


    public class user {
        private String id;
        private String username;
        private String email;
        private String group;
        private String sex;
        private String avatar;
        private String firstname;
        private String secondname;

        public user(String id, String username, String email, String group,String sex,String avatar, String firstname, String secondname){
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.email = email;
            this.group = group;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.avatar = avatar;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.secondname = secondname;
        }

        public user(){}

        public String getId() {return id;}
        public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
        public String getUsername() {return username;}
        public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}
        public String getEmail() {return email;}
        public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
        public String getGroup(){return group;}
        public void setGroup(String group) {this.group = group;}
        public String getSex() {return sex;}
        public void setSex(String sex) {this.sex = sex;}
        public String getAvatar() {return avatar;}
        public void setAvatar(String avatar) {this.avatar = avatar;}
        public String getFirstname() {return firstname;}
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {this.firstname = firstname;}
        public String getSecondname() {return secondname;}
        public void setSecondname(String secondname) {this.secondname = secondname;}



    }

    public interface Api{
        public static final String URL ="http://178.62.42.66/api/v1";
        static final String USERS = "/users/{name}/";


        @GET(USERS)
       user   users(@Path("name") String name ,@Header("Authorization") String jwtToken );

        @DELETE("/users/id/{id}/")
        String delete(@Path("id") String id ,@Header("Authorization") String jwtToken );

        @PATCH("/users/id/{id}/")
        void patchUser(@Path("id") String id,@Header("Authorization") String jwtToken, @Body user users, Callback<user> callback  );


    }

    private void patchUser(final user user01, String jwtToken){
        final String token = jwtToken;

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                        .setEndpoint(Api.URL)
                        .build();
                Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
                api.patchUser(id,token, user01,new Callback<user>(){

                    @Override
                    public void success(user signResponse, Response response){

                        TextView idTV2;
                        idTV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
                        String test;
                        test ="test01";
                        idTV2.setText(test);
                        //String name = signResponse.getToken();
                        //Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, SuccessLog.class);
                        //startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error){

                    }
                });



            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void getUsers(String jwtToken){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Api.URL)
                .build();
        Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
        users = api.users(name,jwtToken);
        //api.users(jwtToken);
    }

    private void deleteUser(String jwtToken){
        final String token = jwtToken;

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                        .setEndpoint(Api.URL)
                        .build();
                Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
                api.delete(id, token);



            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    private void fillText(){




        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                getUsers(jwtToken);
                //name = users.getUsername();
                id = users.getId();
                group = users.getGroup();
                email = users.getEmail();
                sex = users.getSex();
                firstname = users.getFirstname();
                lastname = users.getSecondname();



            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextView idTV,usernameTV,emailTV,groupTV,sexTV,firstnameTV,secondnameTV;
        idTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
        usernameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        emailTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        groupTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.group);
        sexTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sex);
        firstnameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        secondnameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        idTV.setText(id);
        usernameTV.setText(name);
        emailTV.setText(email);
        sexTV.setText(sex);
        groupTV.setText(group);
        firstnameTV.setText(firstname);
        secondnameTV.setText(lastname);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.success_log);
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
        aq.id(R.id.avatar).image("http://178.62.42.66/static/images/avatars/default_avatar.png");
       // text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        //uInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);


        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString("token","");
        String uname = sPref.getString("username","");
        jwtToken = "JWT "+savedText;
        name = uname;
        fillText();




                findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        deleteUser(jwtToken);
                        startActivity(new Intent(SuccessLog.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    }
                });

        findViewById(R.id.btnCh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newID = "101";
               users.setId(newID);
                patchUser(users, jwtToken);
            }
        });






        // user [] users;
       /*uInfo.setText(name); //users[0].getUsername();
        text.setText(savedText);*/


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_success_log, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ей больше некуда возвращаться :)
Вчитайтесь в код: вы стартуете тред, в котором создаете RestAdapter, потом вызываете **асинхронно** метод сервиса и сразу же (не дожидаясь ответа) выходите из треда. RestAdapter теперь уже не валиден и вполне может быть удален GC. Ну и плюс обращение к UI элементам нужно делать из UI треда.

Создайте RestAdapter 1 раз и сохраните ссылку на него в поле SuccessLog. Если используете асинхронные версии методов сервиса, то новый тред можно не создавать.

Comment: Как я узнал, этот метод действует асинхронно, и все что связано с тредом я убрал так же объявил адаптер в самом начале, в поле SuccrssLog. Остался только метод и калбек, но все равно ничего не работает.`  api.patchUser(id,jwtToken, users,new Callback<user>(){ ` и все что было дальше с калбеком

Comment: в failure(RetrofitError error) добавьте вывод в лог, может у вас ошибка в реквесте

Comment: еще можно каким нибудь инструментом типа fiddler (в windows) воспользоваться, чтобы посмотреть что реально отсылается/получается

Comment: Добавил вывод в лог и да, действительно переходит в failure(RetrofitError error). Это значит запрос сформирован неправильно или на сервере что то не получается?

Comment: Могут быть обе причины, смотрите запрос/ответ с помощью фидлера.

Comment: Программу я скачал, но она почему то не видит эти запросы.

Comment: Если не видит, значит не отсылается, разбирайтесь почему не отсылается. Смотрите, что за ошибку выдает.